# Legendre trigonometric form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Legendre equation for a function $y(x)$ defined in the interval $-1 < x < 1$

By a change of variable $x = cos \theta$ derive the trigonometric form of Legendre equation for a function $y(cos\theta)$

Legendre equation: $(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + n(n+1)y = 0$

so I just sub $x = cos \theta$ and I get $(1-cos^2 \theta)y'' - 2(cos \theta)y' + n(n+1)y = 0$

I've tried simplifying but can never get it to the answer expected which is

$y'' + \frac{(cos \theta)}{(sin \theta)}y' + n(n+1)y = 0$

could someone show me how to do it? thank you!

Comment: Do not confuse the derivation relatively to $x$ and the derivation relatively to $\theta$. You use the same symbol $y'$ for both which is confusing since $y'$ relatively to $x$ is not equal to $y'$ relatively to $\theta$. If it is difficult for you to avoid the confusion, then use the symbols $dy/dx$ and $dy/d\theta$ instead of y'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : relationships to the change of variable :

[image]

It appears that you still have some difficulties to follow the calculus of the second derivative. Try to study carefully each step below

[image]

Comment: umm how did you get rid of the 2?

Comment: @kennan : What "2" are you talking about ? You just have to put the formulas of the derivatives into the first form of the Legendre equation and you will obtain the second form as expected.

Comment: I tried it and got close to the final form except with a factor of 2 in front of the $cos(\theta)$ due to the $2xy'$ which does not cancel with anything I have...

Comment: If you do correctly the substitution, some simplifications appear and there is no "2" after. Show all the détails of what you have done and we will see where is your mistake. Note that the correct Legendre equation is $y'' + \frac{(cos \theta)}{(sin \theta)}y' + n(n+1)y = 0$ (not with a "-" as it is in your first post).

Comment: okay so I have $(1-cos^2 \theta)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2(cos \theta)\frac{dy}{dx} + n(n+1)y = 0$ then knowing that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-1}{sin\theta}\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-1}{sin^2\theta}\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}$ and subbing that into the first equation (the $(1-cos^2 \theta)$ equals just $sin^2\theta$ from trig identity), I get $\frac{sin^2\theta}{sin^2\theta}\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} + \frac{2cos\theta}{sin\theta}\frac{dy}{d\theta} + n(n+1)y = 0$ and the final answer I get is $\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} + \frac{2cos\theta}{sin\theta}\frac{dy}{d\theta} + n(n+1)y = 0$

Comment: You use a wrong formula for $d^2y/dx^2$. See the correct one in me first answer.

Comment: oh...I can understand how you got the first term but umm how did you get the second term with a cos? I thought it would just equal $\frac{-1}{sin^2\theta}\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}$...

Comment: Look at each step of the calculus of $d^2y/dx^2$ as shown in my first answer. One of the step consists in the derivation of a product of functions $f(\theta)*g(\theta)$ where $f(\theta)=1/sin(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)=dy/d\theta$. As you know, the result is not only one term, but two terms $f'*g+f*g'$. Do not forget one of them.

Comment: I redid it and this time I ended up with $\frac{-1}{sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta} (\frac{cos\theta}{sin\theta}\frac{1}{sin\theta}\frac{dy}{d\theta} - \frac{1}{sin\theta}*1$ however if I multiply that out, the $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ terms turn out different to the ones you have... is the derivative of $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ equal to 1?

Comment: What a mess ! Of course not $dy/d\theta$ is not equal to $1$. I will add to my first answer a more detailed calculus.

Comment: oh okay, thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I understand about the use of the product of functions. That was what was throwing me off I think...Never really understood it. Thank you again~

Comment: @JJacquelin great answer, but If I may, if we work symbolically we will have $\frac{d^2y}{dx}= \frac{d}{dx} ({\frac{dy}{d\theta }}{\frac{d\theta}{dx }})
\\ ={\frac{dy}{d\theta }}{\frac{d^2\theta}{dx^2 }} + {\frac{d ^2 y}{d \theta ^2 }}({\frac{d \theta}{dx }})^2$ so if substitute for ${\frac{d\theta}{dx }} = \frac{-1}{sin \theta} $ and ${\frac{d^2  \theta}{dx^2 }} = \frac{cos \theta}{sin^2 \theta } $ we will have a different answer for ${\frac{d^2  y}{dx^2 }} = \frac{dy}{d \theta} \frac{cos \theta}{sin^2 \theta } + (\frac{-1}{sin \theta})^2 \frac{d^2y}{d \theta^2}$ did I made a wrong step?

Comment: $d^2\theta/dx^2$ is not equal to $cos(\theta)/sin^2(\theta)$ because you derivate $-1/sin(\theta)$ relativeli to $\theta$ instead of relatively to $x$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\cos\theta$. Then
$$
     \frac{d}{d\theta}=\frac{dx}{d\theta}\frac{d}{dx}=-\sin\theta\frac{d}{dx}
$$
There's nothing much to do with the $n(n+1)y$ term. So I'll ignore that.
$$
\begin{align}
    (1-x^{2})\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-2x\frac{dy}{dx} & =\frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x^{2})\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
       & = -\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin\theta\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right) \\
       & =\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right) \\
       & =\frac{d^{2}y}{d\theta^{2}}+\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\frac{dy}{d\theta}.
\end{align}
$$